# Getting second element of a tuple (in a list of tuples) as a string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have an output that is a list of tuples. It looks like this:

```
annot1=[(402L, u"[It's very seldom that you're blessed to find your equal]"), 
        (415L, u'[He very seldom has them in this show or his movies]')…
```

I need to use the second part of the tuple only to apply ‘split’ and get each word on the sentence separately.

At this point, I’m not able to isolate the second part of the tuple (the text).

This is my code:

```
def scope_match(annot1):
    scope = annot1[1:]
    scope_string = ‘’.join(scope)
    scope_set = set(scope_string.split(' '))
```

But I get:

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found`

I tried to use annot1[1] but it gives me the second index of the text instead of the second element of the tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this with list comprehensions:

```
annot1=[(402L, u"[It's very seldom that you're blessed to find your equal]"), 
        (415L, u'[He very seldom has them in this show or his movies]')]
print [a[1].strip('[]').encode('utf-8').split() for a in annot1]
```

Output:

```
[["It's", 'very', 'seldom', 'that', "you're", 'blessed', 'to', 'find', 'your', 'equal'], ['He', 'very', 'seldom', 'has', 'them', 'in', 'this', 'show', 'or', 'his', 'movies']]
```

You can calculate the intersection of strings in corresponding positions in annot1 and annot2 like this:

```
for x,y in zip(annot1,annot2):
    print set(x[1].strip('[]').encode('utf-8').split()).intersection(y[1].strip('[]').encode('utf-8').split())
```

Comment: I need to pass `intersection()` on the output (I have two outputs I need to find common words). How can I get it out of a list? `intersection` won't take a list.

Comment: I didn't get you. Do you want to calculate intersection between two lists or multiple lists? Because annot1 seems to contain multiple tuples according to how you defined it in the question.

Comment: I want to calculate intersections between the second element (a string) of two lists of tuples.
I have `annot1` and `annot2` (with tuples like shown above), and I need to compare the second element of tuple1 in annot1 with the second element of tuple1 in annot2; then second element of tuple2 in annot1 with the second element of tuple2 in annot2... etc

Comment: Always ask questions by giving full context of your problem. If you are going to ask only a part of question then you might not get an appropriate solution.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad. You helped me a lot. Thanks for the advice too. It's hard to write summaries here. I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

`annot1` is a list of tuples. To get the string from each of the elements, you can do something like this

```
def scope_match(annot1):
    for pair in annot1:
        string = pair[1]
        print string  # or whatever you want to do
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. do you know what could happen?...

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to access a long as a list. Are you sure `annot1` is a list of tuples? Sounds like the other guy has you covered though.